# Using static pages on Wordpress site

Tags: customization

I built a few static pages in HTML while I was practicing some techniques. I would like to include those pages (and that hard work) in a word press site.

I have already created the WP page that hold the 6 items that I want to use as links to my work. I would like to link to another spot on my server or site that will then display the already-created sites and or pages. (some of my work is a complete site some of it is single-page).

- Can I even do this?
- Do I have to change all my already-created HTML files to PHP?
- Can I link to static HTML sites? (that would be ideal)
- I have tried copying and pasting the straight HTML from the pages into the text editor on the WP page, nothing happened.

Thanks for your help,

Josh

Comment: Related answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90241/dynamic-content-in-a-static-page/90247#90247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making your own [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages).

Start by moving the files into your WordPress theme folder, and giving them a name. Like `page-foo.php`, `page-bar.php`, so on.

Then on the top of these new files add PHP like the below, changing the `Template Name` to something that makes sense to you.

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Foo
*/
?>
```

Then place your code under this header.

Go into WordPress wp-admin, go to Pages and add a new page. Then on the right under the `Page Attributes` widget, select the Template name that corresponds with your content that you want to display for that page.

Comment: Great, thanks Pat. That was the direction I was leaning. For all of my pages I am going to just make a template page. Do you think that it is ok to just make a template for each new type of specific page? If I want to make a hundred individual pages is that still ok? Performance wise. I can't think of any reasons why not.

Comment: I don't think it'll add to much overhead if you made 100 separate template files since wordpress will only call that file when its needed. It might make you go a little crazy though having that much to manage. PHP is supposed to make things easier, not harder (although some developers would disagree) :)