# Modify just ONE page based on a template

Tags: templates

I am new to wordpress. I have been given a site to customise.

I want to modify just one of the pages to include a php calendar which links to a mysql database, so I will want to run my own PHP code on one of the pages.

The majority of the template is fine but it uses 1 third of the main window ( below the menu etc.. ) to show a scrolling window of pictures. I want to remove that but just for one page not the whole template ?

Sorry if it sounds a bit simplistic but once I've done this I can address the calendar issue

thanks

Comment: This is too broad/vague to answer. We need more details on the template (slug/name), the page (ID/slug/title), the code etc. Please edit your question and include all relevant information. Then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Why not create a template just for that one page? For example: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/90241/21376

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new page template based on your current page template. Without any example code it is hard to give you a specific example, but here's an approach:

Copy `page.php` to a new file and name it `page-wide.php`. The prefix `page-` is significant because it triggers WordPress' [template hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

At the top of this copied page's source code, make sure the PHP tag begins with something like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Page Example
*/
?>
```

Then, inside WordPress admin, when editing a page, you will have a dropdown box that lets your specify which page template this page should use. It will show up as "Custom Page Example" in the dropdown (in this example).

The point here is that you can create, for example, a `page-wide.php`, that is almost exactly like your normal `page.php` but without a sidebar or an extra wide body `class` which you've designed with CSS.