# Submit form to another template (ugly url)

Tags: templates, redirect, page-template, forms

I've created a submit form with some filters that makes a query request:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/list-items.php">
my form here...
</form>
```

Created a **list-items.php** in the theme directory and it redirects to:

`http://sitename/wp-content/themes/theme-name/list-items.php?allthevariables`

But it seems that Wordpress is not even started this way, because none of its functions are working.

Is there a way that I can make the form redirects to:

`http://sitename/list-items?allthevariables`

How can I make the last URL open the file *list-items.php* in the theme directory?

Comment: I am fairly certain your question is a duplicate of this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90247/21376

Comment: So there's no way to create a file that will be used without before that a page is created manually?

Comment: You can probably use an [endpoint](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=endpoint) but I haven't tried.